# airflow kubernetes pod operator retry no working

Tags: airflow, kubernetes-pod

I am running airflow 1.10.12 in CeleryExecutor mode on Kubernetes cluster. This airflow DAG will create a Pod on the same Kubernetes cluster but in a different namespace.

On a good run, pod will run spark job successfully. But if it fails, airflow should retry. By retrying, the failed pod should receive a new label, metadata.labels.already_checked: 'True' on the first retry attempt and on the second retry attempt a new pod should be launched. However, a new label is not being marked as intended.

A snapshot of error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 282, in execute
    final_state, result = self.handle_pod_overlap(labels, try_numbers_match, launcher, pod_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 312, in handle_pod_overlap
    final_state, result = self.monitor_launched_pod(launcher, pod_list.items[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 432, in monitor_launched_pod
    'Pod returned a failure: {state}'.format(state=final_state)
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Pod returned a failure: failed
```

Comment: Is the failed old pod still alive?

Comment: I attempt to retry airflow task by clearing it after old pod has terminated.

Comment: @HenryCarter can you see if the following issue https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12111 is relevant to your case?